# Creating JQGrid colModel from a javascript string variable

Tags: jqgrid

I am facing an issue while making a common grid control.

When I put

colModel:[ {name:"ID", index: "ID", width: 400, align: "Left"},{name:"Description", index: "Description", width: 400, align: "Left"}],
It works.

When I am trying to replace the ColModel by a string variable I am not getting right display. colModel:[ColDisplay],

The problem is the following. When we put a string variable it comes like the following (with starting ending ‘)
‘{name:"ID", index: "ID", width: 400, align: "Left"},{name:"Description", index: "Description", width: 400, align: "Left"}’

If you put colModel:[ ‘{name:"ID", index: "ID", width: 400, align: "Left"},{name:"Description", index: "Description", width: 400, align: "Left"}’],

It is not able to understand the Columns.

Any solutions for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try eval("([" + ColModel + "])")
2. [Get FireBug](http://www.getfirebug.org)

Comment: ColModel = '{name:"ID", index: "ID", width: 400, align: "Left"},{name:"Description", index: "Description", width: 400, align: "Left"}'; My ColModel string is as above and added it as below to the jQuery.

colModel:[eval("(" + ColModel + ")")],

Only one column is getting displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The `[]` indicate that its is an array.

Try this

```
var ColModel = [{name:"ID", index: "ID", width: 400, align: "Left"},{name:"Description", index: "Description", width: 400, align: "Left"}]

$("#gridid").jqGrid({
~
colModel:ColModel
~});
```